# How does an empty pair of "proof qed" work in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

In the Isabelle 2020 documentation, classes.pdf pp.10, there is a strange-looking proof sequence: `proof qed auto` (separated into three lines for illustration purposes), which really confuses me:

```
interpretation list_monoid: monoid append "[]"
proof
qed
auto
```

So the proof seems to be empty (between `proof` and `qed`), then it's followed by an `auto`. If the mouse is placed at proof, then it shows three goals:

```
goal (3 subgoals):
 1. ⋀x y z. (x @ y) @ z = x @ y @ z
 2. ⋀x. [] @ x = x
 3. ⋀x. x @ [] = x
```

At the `qed`, the goals disappear. Then, there is the `auto` that appears to do nothing.

*Can someone help explain how the `proof qed ...` structure works?*

*In terms of Izar vs the apply-style modes, at each of the `proof, qed` and `auto` lines, which mode is the system in?*

Answer (score 1):

An explanation of the `qed m` paradigm can be found in the official documentation (Isar-ref) in subsection 6.4.2:

> `proof` : *proof(prove) -> proof(state)*

> `qed` : *proof(state) -> proof(state) | local_theory | theory*

> 1. An initial refinement step `proof m1` reduces a newly stated goal to a
>    number of sub-goals that are to be solved later. Facts are passed to
>    `m1` for forward chaining, if so indicated by proof (chain) mode.

> 2. A terminal conclusion step `qed m2` is intended to solve remaining
>    goals. No facts are passed to `m2`.

There is a more detailed explanation if you continue reading:

> `proof m1` refines the goal by proof method `m1`; facts for forward
> chaining are passed if so indicated by proof (chain) mode.

> `qed m2` refines any remaining goals by proof method `m2` and concludes the sub-proof by assumption. If the goal had been `show`, some pending sub-goal is solved as well by the rule resulting from the result exported into the enclosing goal context. Thus `qed` may fail for two reasons: either `m2` fails, or the resulting rule does not fit to any pending goal of the enclosing context.

Thus, it is perfectly legal to pass a method after `qed` in an attempt to solve the goals that remain. In the example above, effectively, all goals that remain after the application of the default refinement step invoked by `proof` are solved by `auto`.

---

`by m1 m2` can often be used instead of `proof m1 qed m2` (the only difference is that `by m1 m2` backtracks across both `m1` and `m2`). Thus, I believe that another conventional way to prove the theorem in the original question would be

```
interpretation list_monoid: monoid append "[]"
  by unfold_locales auto
```

For the description of `by` also see subsection 6.4.2 in Isar-ref.

A slightly less conventional way to prove the theorem, but even closer to the `proof qed auto` paradigm in the original question would be

```
interpretation list_monoid: monoid append "[]"
  apply standard 
  apply auto
  done
```

Finally, of course, you do not need to solve all of the goals using the `qed m` paradigm. The most standard use case for this paradigm is exhibited in the code listing below:

```
interpretation list_monoid: monoid append "[]"
proof
  show 
    "(x @ y) @ z = x @ y @ z" 
    "[] @ x = x"
    for x y z :: "'a list"
    by auto
qed auto
```

---

The answer was written based on Isabelle2021-RC2.